# query update or insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello I would like to update or insert an application but it shows me error. knowing that if I remove the update or query works

```
UPDATE OR INSERT  INTO stat_alert(`DAT`,`provider`,`CI`,`cell`,`BSC`,`cmts`,`nbr`,`TYPE`)
     SELECT CC.DAT,CC.provider,CC.CI,CC.cell,CC.BSC,CC.cmts, CONCAT(CC.C,'C, ',MM.M ,'M') AS nbr,'C' AS TYPE  FROM 
     (SELECT DAT,provider,CI,cell,BSC,cmts,COUNT(*) AS C FROM alertes_bss2 WHERE Criticity = 'C' GROUP BY cell,Criticity ) AS CC,
     (SELECT DAT,provider,CI,cell,BSC,cmts,COUNT(*) AS M FROM alertes_bss2 WHERE Criticity = 'M' GROUP BY cell,Criticity) AS MM WHERE MM.cell = CC.cell
      UNION SELECT DAT,provider,CI,cell,BSC,cmts, CONCAT(COUNT(*) ,'C') AS nbr,'C' AS TYPE FROM alertes_bss2 WHERE Criticity = 'C' AND cell NOT IN
       (SELECT cell FROM alertes_bss2 WHERE Criticity = 'M') GROUP BY DAT,provider,CI,cell,BSC,Criticity 
      UNION SELECT DAT,provider,CI,cell,BSC,cmts, CONCAT(COUNT(*) ,'M') AS nbr,'M' AS TYPE FROM alertes_bss2 WHERE Criticity = 'M' AND cell NOT IN 
      (SELECT cell FROM alertes_bss2 WHERE Criticity = 'C') GROUP BY DAT,provider,CI,cell,BSC,Criticity;
```

I have this error :

```
Query: UPDATE OR INSERT INTO stat_alert(`DAT`,`provider`,`CI`,`cell`,`BSC`,`cmts`,`nbr`,`TYPE`) SELECT CC.DAT,CC.provider,CC.CI,CC.cell...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR INSERT  INTO stat_alert(`DAT`,`provider`,`CI`,`cell`,`BSC`,`cmts`,`nbr`,`TYPE' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.003 sec
---------------------------------------------------
```

who can help me

Comment: There must be a [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) somewhere, describing the syntax of those statements....

Comment: Where did you get that horrible syntax `UPDATE OR INSERT  INTO`?

Comment: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-update-or-insert.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for `REPLACE`? [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use UPDATE AND INSERT together...............

You need to handle it in code that whether need to be updated the data or Insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `UPDATE OR INSERT` in Mysql.You have to check the record is present into the database or not.If it is present then `UPDATE` otherwise use `INSERT`.